# How to use Java's lambda expressions to print an array?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

How can I achieve the following array print using Java 8's lambda expressions?

```
int[] values = new int[16];
// Populate values

for (int value : values) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(value, 16));
}
```

Comment: Or `Arrays.stream(values).forEach(i -> System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(i, 16)));`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
Arrays.stream(values)
      .mapToObj(i -> Integer.toUnsignedString(i, 16))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 24):

```
String[] nums = {"three","two","one"};
Arrays.stream(nums).forEach(num -> System.out.println(num));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can print the array in a simple way just by using one line of code instead of writing a loop, using Java8 features i.e. `stream` and `method` references

Example:

```
int arrayName[] = new int[size];

Arrays.stream(arrayName).forEach(System.out::println); //This will iterate and print each element of the array.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IntStream.of(values)
            .mapToObj(i -> Integer.toUnsignedString(i, 16))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

is an alternative (clearer IMO) to `Arrays.stream()`.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to println the int. He wants to print the result of `Integer.toUnsignedString(i, 16)`.

Comment: @JBNizet: thanks, I didn't read the question properly. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can convert array to list and make use of lambda as below using new forEach method.

```
int[] values = new int[16];
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(values);
list.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(values)` will create a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: make it as Integer array and try it.. like Integer[] values = new Integer[16];

Comment: I know... I was just pointing out that your example won't compile, as the OP have an array of primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

For simply printing integer, we don't need to map to any new object

```
Arrays.stream(arrInt1)            
      .forEach(i ->{
          System.out.print(i);
          System.out.print("\t");
      });
```

Comment: I wonder what is so fundamentally different in your answer when you look at [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684419/1816580).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print given String[] as space separated between each element
e.g.

```
String[] namesArray= new String[]{
"sam","ram","bam"};
```

as

```
sam ram bam
```

you can use this code

```
Arrays.stream(stringArray).map(stringElement ->  stringElement+” ”).forEach(System.out :: print);
```

and in case if you want to print int[] with space between elements
things get slightly trickier as you need to convert int to String and then add space

```
int[] intArray= new int[]{
1,2,3,4};
```

as

```
1 2 3 4
```

you can use below code

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).mapToObject(intElement -> Integer.toUnsignedString(intElement) + “ ”).forEach(System.out :: print);
```